# Google Play Private Channel - one Google account for many devices

Tags: android, google-play

I am setting up a Google Play Private Channel for a company I'm working for.  The instructions say that you need a Google Apps for Business account to download the app from the private channel.  We have many sales reps who need to continuously upgrade when there is a new release pushed to the private channel.

Can we share one Google Apps for Business account for many users?

I'd like to have one account, sales@company.com, that they all share.  The reason for this being that I don't want to propose a solution that would cost the company $5/month/user, which is the cost of a Google Apps for Business account!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you only need to restrict downloads to a particular set of users, you don't actually need a Google Play Private Channel: you can use the [beta testing feature of Google Play](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/3131213) to publish the app only to a 'beta' channel and only allow your sales reps access to the Google Group you set up with access to the beta channel.

As long as you never publishing a production version, the app remains visible only to those 'beta testers' i.e., your sales reps and not to the wider Google Play audience.

Comment: sounds like a great idea and i checked it out.. would definitely use it for other projects but the project manager really just wants the agents to download the app right through the play market  :-/

Comment: You download beta and alpha channel apps directly from the Play Store, just like normal apps. Access is just limited to particular Google+ communities or Google Groups which your agents would need to be invited to/join.

Comment: You're right! I pushed a new version to Beta, and I didn't see the update in Play after a couple of hours.  I checked again the next day and the new version was there and I can update through Play. Thanks!

Comment: Can I just have one "beta tester", sales@company.com, and every device uses that account?

Comment: Beta/alpha testing access is still Google Group/Google+ community controlled. There's nothing stopping you only adding a single sales@company.com email address to the Google Group and effectively only having a single account with access to the app.

Comment: I just tried again with a new app... I can see the app on the Google Play store in a browser on my desktop PC, but I can't see the app in a browser or in the Google Play app on my tablet... I'm logged in with the same account on both the PC and the tablet.

Comment: Apps that don't have a release version are not indexed so they won't show up in search results, but direct links should work fine. Is that not the case?

Comment: I had to login to my gmail account through the browser on the tablet in order to see the app through the direct link.